# Mailx command from a C Program

Tags: c, shell, system, mailx

What I am trying to do, is have my c program execute a function that uses the system() function with mailx. When I output the variable that holds the const *char that the system() function needs it looks fine. But I do not get the email. Yet when I run the mailx command via CLI, I get the email. Here is my code: Thank you in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void send_email(char *to_who, char *subject, char *message)
{
    char command[1024];
    char command_buffer[1024];  

    if (snprintf(command_buffer, sizeof(command_buffer), "echo \"%s\" | mailx -s \"%s\" %s", message, subject, to_who) >= sizeof(command_buffer))
    {
        printf("Command Buffer Overload");
    }

    strcpy(command, command_buffer);
    system(command);

    //Check to see command contents
    printf("%s", command);  
}

int main ()
{

 send_email("user@email.com","C Email Test", "Test Email with C");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209141/how-do-i-execute-a-shell-built-in-command-with-a-c-function> HTH

Comment: For starters would suggest you check the return value of `system` to get the command return status and what the precise error code is if it failed. (Aside: it's a bit pointless to `strcpy` into a new buffer. Just use the result of the `snprintf` directly).

Comment: @kaylum how do I return the value of the system function?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `int rval = system(..);`. Then have conditional checks on `rval` and print out that value for debugging.

Comment: @kaylum the value returned is 0

Comment: @jaaq I took a look at the thread and I tried a few of things, but still no luck

Comment: I tried your program and it worked fine.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, in that case it must be somethin wrong with my Pi, would you happen to have an idea of what it might be?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why it would work from the CLI but not from C on the same machine. Are you running the program from a different account? Maybe the `mailx` command isn't in its `$PATH`. Try using the full path to the command.

Comment: @Barmar I tried to run the program with the full path /usr/bin/mailx and still same issue. Works on terminal but  not in the C. This is really odd

Comment: Does the `system()` function work with other commands, e.g. `system("echo foo");`?