# Implementing terminal commands with c

Tags: c, terminal

I have to write the c program that executes terminal commands which are in this order :

1. cd ../../etc
2. chmod a+x file
3. cd alice/password
4. more password

so if I have attack.c then by ./attack, all these should be implemented on the terminal.
I tried using `execvp()` but its just not happening.

Comment: "that implements" do you want to say "that executes"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I execute a Shell built-in command with a C function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209141/how-do-i-execute-a-shell-built-in-command-with-a-c-function)

Comment: Question is kind of similar but the solution is not working.I just want like a conversion of these four commands

Answer (score 4):

You can run shell commands in C using the system() command (works in linux)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  system("cd ../../etc; chmod a + x file; cd alice/password; cat password");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bonus: figure out why this doesn't do what I think you want.

Comment: @stolenmoment Check the modified version please