# libssh tunnel echoing input

Tags: c, linux, libssh

I've created my own SSH reverse tunnel using libssh by following the tutorials at http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutorial.html and piecing things together from various other samples.  However, now, all I get is the client echoing back whatever is inputted via the tunnel connection.  I'm trying to get to the point where I can execute commands through the reverse tunnel (ex: `ls -al`).

The reverse tunnel (initiated on the client side):

```
int reverse_loop(ssh_session session){
    ssh_channel channel;
    int rc; 
    int nbytes, nwritten;
    char buf[256];
    int port = 0;

    rc = ssh_channel_listen_forward(session, NULL, 43434, NULL); 

    if (rc != SSH_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening remote port %s\n", ssh_get_error(session));
        return rc; 
    }   

    channel = ssh_channel_accept_forward(session, 60000, &port);
    if (channel == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error waiting for incoming connection: %s\n", ssh_get_error(session)); 
        return SSH_ERROR;
    }   

    while(1){
        printf("In loop\n");
        nbytes = ssh_channel_read(channel, buf, sizeof(buf), 0); 
        if (nbytes < 0){ 
            fprintf(stderr, "Error reading incoming data: %s\n", ssh_get_error(session));
            ssh_channel_send_eof(channel);
            ssh_channel_free(channel);
            return SSH_ERROR;
        }
        printf("read channel\n");



        if (nbytes > 0){ 
            nwritten = ssh_channel_write(channel, buf, nbytes);
            if (nwritten != nbytes){
                fprintf(stderr, "Error sending answer: %s\n", ssh_get_error(session));
                ssh_channel_send_eof(channel);
                ssh_channel_free(channel);                                                                            
                return SSH_ERROR;
            }
            printf("Wrote channel\n");
        }
        printf("sent answer!\n");
    }
    // close_channel
    ssh_channel_send_eof(channel);
    ssh_channel_free(channel);

    return SSH_OK;
}
```

Running this, the reverse session is initiated.  So, from the SSH server, I can run:

```
> nc localhost 43434
ls (this is what I sent)
ls (this is what I receive)
pwd (this is what I sent)
pwd (this is what I receive)
```

Then on the client side, I see this output:

```
In loop
read channel
Wrote channel
sent answer!
In loop
```

What I'm looking for are the actual results of running `ls` or `pwd` (or whatever system command the user inputs, not the echo.  Can anyone direct me on the step that I missed to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Don’t understand the question, just execute the commands instead of just echoing them back?

Comment: @Fredrik - I type in `ls` and and would expect to get a response back of the files in a directory, not the command I sent.

Comment: Why not just execute the commands when you recieve them and echo back the result?

Comment: @Fredrik I guess that's my question.  How?  `ssh_channel_request_exec(buf)` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209141/how-do-i-execute-a-shell-built-in-command-with-a-c-function

Comment: @Fredrik I think I ran across this answer at some point.  My issue is where the command being passed in is stored, which I can't seem to find (is it in `nbytes`, `buf`, etc.?).  I also tried going this route (http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_command.html), but run into the same problem of not being able to find the command being passed in any of the variables.

Comment: The command is stored in your buf variable. It gets placed there after you call ssh_channel_read