# using C -programming, how to get process name from process id on windows

Tags: c, process

i'm having process id from Task manager, i need to get the process name (complete with extension) from it.
is it possible?
i checked other questions, they are mostly command based.

Comment: If they are command based, why don't you run .cmd from a C module?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209141/how-do-i-execute-a-shell-built-in-command-with-a-c-function

Comment: are you using Windows7 Task manager?

Comment: Windows 10, does this makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean 'get the .exe filename by process ID' from C code?

If so, you may have interesting in `OpenProcess()` and following `GetModuleFileNameEx()`.
Don't forget to `CloseHandle()` after you get the exe filename. :)

Comment: thanks for the pointers, calling GetModuleBaseName() before CloseHandle(), seems answer for the query.